# Deploy Grails to a Sub-Context Path

Tags: tomcat, grails, groovy

I would like to deploy a grails war to a sub context path but when I try this the application will not load and an error filterStart so I'm either missing something or grails can't be deployed to a sub-context. Is there any way to load grails in a sub context?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by 'sub-context path'? Please provide an example.

Comment: In tomcat you can deploy a war to lets say /ex then you can deploy another war to a sub context say /ex/sub That works fine for most war files but a grails based war will always have an error to my testing even with an very basic war deployed at /ex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought I'd leave an answer here for anyone who comes along since I've been trying to solve this problem myself.

One trick is to set use the hash/pound sign (#) in the .war file name:

> api#1.2.war

Which results in the following app context:

> http://localhost:8080/api/1.2/

I've tested this in Tomcat 7.

One reason why I wanted this is so that I can automatically ship different versions running side by side with the following grails BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.project.war.file = "target/api#${appVersion}.war"
```

This works great with Tomcat 7, I'm unsure about other versions.

However, what I would really like to do is set it up so that Tomcat uses the context from my Grails **Config.groovy** or **application.properties** files.

**Update 1:** I'm using Grails 1.3.7.

**Update 2:** Successfully tested by user miek in Tomcat 6. Thanks miek!

Comment: What version of grails are you using?

Comment: Worked brilliantly in Tomcat 6 as well. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @JeffBeck Did this help you at all? If so could you accept please.

Comment: @TonyDay sorry by the time you answered in 2011 I no longer worked with the company that was having the problem but the solution you have above should be correct. I'll go ahead and accept because it seems correct but I haven't been able to confirm the solution in the same environment.

Comment: @JeffBeck Sorry, you're right - it's been that long since I answered actually that I forgot about that! Thanks for accepting either way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just a shoot from the hip: add a file /web-app/META-INF/context.xml to your application with these contents:

```
<Context path="/ex/sub" />
```

I'm not sure if that works, but it's worth a try.